# Why is it giving me a mismatch error?

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

When the user is prompted to give a survery of my excel document, I have them enter in a number between 1 and 10. The Sub Test is to eliminate Strings and numbers outside of 1 through 10. This sub works. If the user enters a number 1 through 10 the first time, the program works like a charm. However, there is an error that pops up if the user enters a string first and then puts in an integer from 1-10. It is a run-time error 13 type mismatch. I have commented out the line that pops up as an error. However, the email goes through still. Also, if you can explain why I have to redefine my RANK integer, that would also help. Option Explicit is not working like I read about in my book. Thank you! If you have any questions, please let me know!!

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim RANK As Long


Call Test

RANK = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value  '((((THIS IS THE LINE THAT PROMPTS THE ERROR)))
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
.To = "(my email is inserted here)"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Create Database Overall Ranking"
.Body = "The rank a company gave me was a " & RANK & "."

.send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Unload UserForm1

End Sub

Sub Test()
Dim MyVar, MyCheck
Dim RANK As Long
 MyVar = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text ' Assign value.
 MyCheck = IsNumeric(MyVar) ' Returns True.

If MyCheck = True Then
RANK = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

If RANK > 10 Or RANK < 1 Then

MsgBox "Please input a number between 1 and 10.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Number"
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = ""
On Error Resume Next
Unload UserForm1
UserForm1.Show
Else
End If
Else
MsgBox "Please input a number and not text.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Input"
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = ""
On Error Resume Next
Unload UserForm1
UserForm1.Show
End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: THE CODE THAT WORKS!!!

I got it to work....here is the code. I just had the test to make sure that it is a number and i ran the number as a string.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim SurveyNum As String


Call Test

SurveyNum = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
.To = "(MY EMAIL HERE)"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Create Database Overall Ranking"
.Body = "The rank a company gave me was a " & SurveyNum & "."

.send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Unload UserForm1

End Sub
Sub Test()
Dim MyVar, MyCheck
Dim SurveyNum2 As Double
 MyVar = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text ' Assign value.
 MyCheck = IsNumeric(MyVar) ' Returns True.

If MyCheck = True Then
SurveyNum2 = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

If SurveyNum2 > 10 Or SurveyNum2 < 1 Then

MsgBox "Please input a number between 1 and 10.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Number"
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = ""
On Error Resume Next
Unload UserForm1
UserForm1.Show
Else
End If
Else
MsgBox "Please input a number and not text.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Input"
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = ""
On Error Resume Next
Unload UserForm1
UserForm1.Show
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: when you set OutMail set it to a MailItem not just CreateItem(0).  like Set OutMail = New OUtlook.MailItem

Comment: This did not work.

Set OutMail = NewOUtlook.MailItem

Comment: use the debugger and tell us which line is causing the issue

Comment: I re-created your code on my machine and it works fine....

Comment: did you enter in a string first...then inserted a integer the second time and it didn't give you an error?

Comment: you said RANK = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value  '((((THIS IS THE LINE THAT PROMPTS THE ERROR)))   try casting it to a long like so   RANK = CLng(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value)  '((((THIS IS THE LINE THAT PROMPTS THE ERROR)))

Comment: I have already defined the variable RANK as Long at the beginning of the code. Even though I was pretty sure this wasn't going to work, I tried it anyway, hoping I was wrong. LOL. Let me re-phrase the question. What is a run-time error 13 type mismatch mean? I don't fully understand what that means.

Comment: it means you are putting something other than a long in a datatype to be used for a long.   What value does the textbox on the form contain?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on that may be causing an issue.

Rank is a function that already exists in VBA. You may be running into problems using this same name for something user-defined. Although I don't think that is what is giving you the error.

I think the problem lies with declaring RANK as long. The long data type, as I understand it, is an integer. If the value you are passing to this data type is not an integer, it could be the culprit.

I would rename the rank variable and redefine it as double and see what that does for you.

**EDIT with code**

I managed to fix the code. I don't know exactly what was causing the issue but there are a few items I changed.

1. You declared separate variables in the same procedure for the same textbook value, but were using different data types (RANK as Long and myVar as Variant in the Test procedure)
2. I also cleaned up a few items to make the code flow a bit better.

Here's the code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim SurveyNum As Double

    If Test = True Then

        SurveyNum = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        OutApp.Session.Logon
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = "(my email is inserted here)"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Create Database Overall Ranking"
            .Body = "The rank a company gave me was a " & SurveyNum & "."

            .send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing

        Unload UserForm1
    End If
End Sub

Function Test() As Boolean
    Dim MyVar As Double
    Dim MyCheck As Boolean

    MyVar = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value ' Assign value.
    MyCheck = IsNumeric(MyVar) ' Returns True.

    If MyCheck = True Then

        If MyVar > 10 Or MyVar < 1 Then

            MsgBox "Please input a number between 1 and 10.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Number"
            UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = ""
            On Error Resume Next
            Test = False
        Else
            Test = True
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Please input a number and not text.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Input"
        UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        Test = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: or define it as a variant

Comment: You could define as a variant, although that's not a best practice. See [here - Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx) for some discussion.

Comment: First off, I switched my variable name from RANK to SurveyNum. Second, I switched it from Long to Double. However, this does not solve the error that is popping up. Is there a chance that the program is storing the string I put in first and once a good integer is put through then it realizes that there is a problem with having a string in the SurveyNum value. Is there a way to clear my stored value in my code so that the SurveyNum gets reset?

Comment: i got it to work...See the question...and the EDIT is the answer

Comment: I see your answer. It works, but I wouldn't recommend declaring it as string if you ever need to use it as a number. See my edit above. It will be less prone to errors due to not declaring the same variable twice.